# The problem with load .glb model in Simplify Modifator (three.js)

Tags: three.js, simplify

I'm trying to use Simplify Modifator, but every time I upload my .glb file I've tried dozens of them, I've also tried different models directly from the examples in three.js, and none of them work except for the one that is defautlly set there), it gives me this error every time I load it:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clone')

I'm only using models with one material (no textures), what am I doing wrong, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve the problem. The model must be composed of a whole mesh, as one component, it should not contain multiple groups. It also needs to be cleaned of elements like light, cameras, etc that you sometimes have defautlly set in native 3D software. Hope this helps you!